# Extracting attention weights of each token at each layer of transformer in python

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am doing some NLP and I am interested in extracting attention weights of individual test token at each layer of transformer via Python (PyTorch, TensorFlow, etc.)

Is coding up a Transformer (any transformers like Transformer-XL, OpenAL-GPT, GPT2 ,etc.) from the scratch the only way to get attention weights of individual test token at each transformer layer? Is there easier way to perform this task in Python? More specifically, can Keras-transformer be used for this purpose? If someone can provide me with some example code, it will be great!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The type of API you are probably is looking for is [BertViz](https://github.com/jessevig/bertviz) which is a tool for visualizing attention in the Transformer model (BERT, GPT-2, XLNet, and RoBERTa).

Also, Hugginface's [transformer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) API is an excellent source to play with Transformer architecture. OpenNMT is another helpful API to use the transformer. You may check out the [documentation](http://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/FAQ.html#how-do-i-use-the-transformer-model).